# Color loss and clarity issues in Canon T2i

Tags: canon, image-quality

I have a cannon t2i. About two years old now. It used to take great Sharp detailed pictures in all modes and long and short lens. Now when shooting at long distance the image comes out blurry or nor very sharp at all. Used to be able to see objects very clearly at distance ( like individual blades of grass). Now not very well. Also the colors appear bleached out and when loaded into my cannon photo program they seem to pulse a color then go into the bleached looked. Any help on this? Looking for some kind.of idea if I need to have it repaired. Thanks

Comment: When you say "long and short lens", do you mean the same lens zoomed in or out, or that you've tried different lenses? In either case, which lenses have you tried?

Comment: Also, are you shooting in RAW or JPEG? Have you tried changing the JPEG settings?

Comment: You will not get any reliable answer unless you post some examples. Different issues can arise such as misfocus, broken stabilization, stuck focus motor, etc but without seeing, it could be anything.

Comment: How long is "long distance"? Also, when you have this blurry problem, what are the environmental conditions like? Is it hazy, or is there a lot of moisture in the air? I sometimes use a $13,500 840mm lens (probably a lot longer than you are using), and the results are terrible. The reason is water moisture in the air, which at too great of a distance can really warp and blur detail.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two different problems:

1. **The colors** - if when you load the image into an editing program you get a "pulse" of good colors and then everything goes bad that you are probably shooting raw, the in-camera "picture style" that is used to create the preview you see in the "pulse" is good but the editing program is set to automatically apply a different setting that you don't like (for example, the "neutral" setting). try to reset all the editing parameters in your program to the default values.

   To test this switch your camera to shoot JPEGs, if the files come out good than it's your editing program for sure.
2. **The sharpness** - internal elements of the lens can get knocked out of alignment (especially if the camera gets bumped or dropped) - and this causes the lens to not focus the light as well and the image gets softer.

   You can test this by trying the same camera with a different lens or the same lens on a different camera to see if the softness is the fault of the camera body or lens.

   If this is the problem you can't fix this yourself you have to get the camera and lens to be aligned by a trained technician (preferably at certified a service center).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same lens, you may have set it accidentally to manual-focus?
Or you left the camera without a lens mounted on it and without a cap, and the sensor
has now dust ?
Or is it a software issue? Do the pictures look right on the camera display but wrong when you see them on your computer?